# Removing text up to a blank line

Tags: regex, awk, sed

So I have a report log file that represents a bunch of source files that are missing.  I want to clear out the files that are fine.  Given the example, how would I remove the line "The following files have been resolved:" and everything after it until the space?  The length of the number of resolved files in different and therefore I can't use a set number of lines after I see that phrase.

Example:

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Building karaf-parent 1.5.0-SNAPSHOT
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------

 --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:sources (default-cli) @ karaf-parent ---

 The following files have been resolved:
    org.opendaylight.controller:karaf.branding:jar:sources:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
    org.opendaylight.controller:opendaylight-karaf-resources:jar:sources:1.5.0-SNAPSHOT:compile

 The following files have NOT been resolved:
    org.apache.karaf.features:standard:xml:sources:3.0.3:runtime
```

Again, the only thing I'm looking for is the package name and the files that have NOT been resolved.

I'm sure that there is some sed/awk command that I can run.  But I just don't use regex enough to know the answer.  :(

When I try to look it up, all I get is "remove blank line", which isn't really what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how would I remove the line "The following files have been resolved:" and everything after it until the space?

I assume by space, you mean the space created by an empty line.

#### Using `sed`:

```
 $ sed '/The following files have been resolved/,/^$/d' file
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Building karaf-parent 1.5.0-SNAPSHOT
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------

 --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:sources (default-cli) @ karaf-parent ---

 The following files have NOT been resolved:
    org.apache.karaf.features:standard:xml:sources:3.0.3:runtime
```

#### Using `awk`

```
$ awk '/The following files have been resolved/,/^$/{next;} 1' file
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Building karaf-parent 1.5.0-SNAPSHOT
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------

 --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:sources (default-cli) @ karaf-parent ---

 The following files have NOT been resolved:
    org.apache.karaf.features:standard:xml:sources:3.0.3:runtime
```

### Alternate Problem: keeping only the unresolved files

```
$ awk '/The following files have NOT been resolved/,/^$/' file
 The following files have NOT been resolved:
    org.apache.karaf.features:standard:xml:sources:3.0.3:runtime
```

Or, without the header:

```
$ awk ' /^$/{f=0} f{print} /The following files have NOT been resolved/{f=1}' file
    org.apache.karaf.features:standard:xml:sources:3.0.3:runtime
```

### Revised Problem

From [a pastebin sample log](http://pastebin.com/wqpBDrwK), none of the empty lines are actually empty.  They all have at least one space.  We can handle that with.  With a POSIX sed, the following should work:

```
sed '/The following files have been resolved/,/^[[:space:]]*$/d' monitor.log
```

`[:space:]` is the unicode-safe way of specifying white space.  If your sed does not support it, then use:

```
sed '/The following files have been resolved/,/^[ \t]*$/d' monitor.log
```

Further, in the unedited log, the lines of interest begin with `[INFO]`.  The following will work whether or not the lines start with `[INFO]`:

```
sed '/The following files have been resolved/,/^\([[]INFO[]]\)\?[ \t\r]*$/d' monitor.log
```

For example, consider this sample (extracted from the pastebin source):

```
$ cat log2
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building yang-data-impl 0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:sources (default-cli) @ yang-data-impl ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-binding:jar:sources:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-common:jar:sources:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:sources:4.0:test
[INFO] 
[INFO] The following files have NOT been resolved:
[INFO]    antlr:antlr:jar:sources:2.7.7:test
[INFO]
```

Our `sed` command works as follows:

```
$ sed '/The following files have been resolved/,/^\([[]INFO[]]\)\?[ \t\r]*$/d' log2
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building yang-data-impl 0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:sources (default-cli) @ yang-data-impl ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] The following files have NOT been resolved:
[INFO]    antlr:antlr:jar:sources:2.7.7:test
[INFO]
```

Comment: you can assume that it remove paragraph and 1st empty line, keeping the rest unchaged (so any following empty line are still present)

Comment: It didn't really seem to work for some reason.  Here's a pastebin of the log.  http://pastebin.com/wqpBDrwK  - I had removed the [INFO] statements earlier with sed 's/^\[INFO\]//g'

Comment: @WrathWolf The problem was that the empty lines actually have an invisible space.  I added a version that works with those whether or not the `[INFO]` is still in the file.

Comment: @John1024 This is amazing.  But for some reason when I run this, it gets to the first reference of "The following files have been resolved" and removes everything after it. --- Everything.  :(

Comment: @WrathWolf That's frustrating: it works for me both on the test files shown above and the full pastebin file.  Give me a moment and I will think of a work-around.  Meanwhile, because it might help identify an incompatibility, what OS and versions of sed and awk are you using?

Comment: @John1024 Mac OSX and iterm.  Not sure the version.  I tried -V and --version.

Comment: @WrathWolf Thanks for the info.  To help narrow down the issue, did this `sed 's/^[INFO]//g'` really remove the `[INFO]`?   (Since, for most seds,  `[` and `]` are regex active characters, one would normally need something like: `sed 's/^[[]INFO[]]//g' instead.)

Comment: @John1024 Got it.  It's sed '/The following files have been resolved/,/^[ \t]*$/d' file

Comment: @WrathWolf Excellent.  I updated the answer to use that form.  Note, though, that `[:space:]` is the modern unicode-safe way of specifying whitespace.  When you get a sed that supports it, you should switch to this form.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 1,/"NOT been resolved:"/d file
```

This works if you are sure that the not resolved lines will be the last entry and no further text (otherwise you will need to grab only the proceeding paragraph). Its works by deleting all lines from line one up to the match.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @John1024 I got on the right track.

However I found the answer to be the following:

```
sed '/The following files have been resolved/,/^[ \t]*$/d' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -n0E 'say $1 while /NOT been resolved:\n(.*?\n)\n/gs`
```